# Shell script to find difference between time stamps in milliseconds unix operating system

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting.

This is the sample date and time that was saved in the UNIX system.
I'm going to use a shell script to cut this date part here.

```
20221010042234.671 - 20221010042234.491
20221010132747.826 - 20221010132747.712
20221010060016.904 - 20221010060016.903
```

Input

```
132747.826 - 132747.712 
060016.904 - 060016.903
042234.671 - 042234.491
```

Expected output

```
0.18
0.11
0.001
```

Our UNIX system doesn't support mktime, use, my
date -d, most of the functions are missing.

I'm looking for assistance in writing a shell script to calculate the time difference.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ print $10-$9 }' Simple subtraction is not working for the 00th and 59th minutes.
```

Comment: So this is `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`? Explains why subtraction doesn't work -- if you wanted it to work you'd convert into something like epoch time, so you just have a number of seconds, not a series of different fields concatenated together to look like a single number.

Comment: Thank you @Charles shall try to convert into epoch timestamp